# Swift 3: CoreData FetchRequest

Tags: core-data, swift3

I was using the following in Swift 2.3

```html
class func getRecord(tableName: String) -> [AnyObject] {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: tableName)
    let requestResult = MyModel.executeRequest(request);
    }
```

where MyModel is some model.
The above code was working fine in Swift 2. Now I have to convert it in Swift 3.
This is what I do in swift3,

```html
let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = tableName.fetchRequest()
```

But surely a string type doesn't have a fetchRequest member. So I am stuck on this stage. Please guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use your modelname.fetchRequset. In your case you have to do as follows,

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<MyModel> = MyModel.fetchRequest()
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3, `NSFetchRequest` became a generic type. And you can use your entity's class's static method `fetchRequest` to get a `NSFetchRequest<Self>`.

For example, if your entity is called `MyModel`, you can get a fetch request like this:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<MyModel> = MyModel.fetchRequest()
```

Then, you can execute it by calling `execute` on a managed object context.

```
try? context.execute(request)
```